# How to get the value of each checkbox inside foreach in angular 9 reactive forms

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I have a checkbox in each row of primeng ptable and also a click function in each checkbox. The code is given below :

```
<ng-template let-productList>
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateStatus(productList.product_id, $event)">
</ng-template>
```

In component.ts :

```
updateStatus(productid: any, e: any) {
      console.log(productid)
  }
```

When I click any checkbox am getting only the first productid in updateStatus function. how can I solve this issue in reactive form?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a name property to your input, otherwise, you cannot differentiate inputs.

```
<input [name]="'product_' + productList.product_id'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing just productList to updatestatus function then in component.ts file, iterate through productList. I think you should be able to access product_id's there.

<input type="checkbox" (change)="updateStatus(productList, $event)">

Comment: I tried but this also passing only first value in all cases.